# What is the equivalent of createStream() in Discors.js v13?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, voice

In Discord.js v12 the way of receiving audio was like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Create a ReadableStream of s16le PCM audio    
const audio = connection.receiver.createStream(user, { mode: 'pcm' });

audio.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('user_audio'));
```

Taken from the official [documentation](https://v12.discordjs.guide/voice/receiving-audio.html#basic-usage).

But there is no such thing in the v13 [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#cheat-sheet).

My question now is, how would one do this with Discord.js v13?
Both create the stream and store the recorded audio locally.

Comment: An example is found here: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/tree/main/packages/voice/examples/recorder